# Trying to map a object attribute to a database column named differently

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am a new user and am using SQLAlchemy with mysql in Python.  I have a customer object that maps to a customer table.  I decided to name the object attribute differently from the column name in the database.  The documentation for SQLAlchemy 1.3.11 indicates that this should be permissible.

My class looks like this

```
class Customer(declarative_base(), PersistentBase.PersistentBase):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    first_name = Column('firstName', String(35), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column('lastName', String(35), nullable=False)
```

When I try to execute some operation like retrieve, I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'firstName'
```

Should I not be able to do that.  My attribute in the class is first_name that is being mapped to a column firstName.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you exactly _"execute some operation like retrieve"_?

Comment: session.query(Customer).get(key)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry.  I had a typo in another part of my code which printed a retrieved object which was causing this error.  My apologies.